# TYPE values in focused text field (like TYPE in selenium RC)- Selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, actionscript

Need :  I have to Type the string inside the focused text area. That text area doesn't have a static xpath.,   Hence I am using

`Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.sendKeys(textarea).perform();`

But this behaves like pasting the values instead of typing. So, in my case browser doesn't shows auto suggestion list.

Does any other option to type the values instead of sendkeys ?

P.S: I am testing this case for Other languages like Hiragana,Katakana,..

Comment: how it could be possible to not have any xpath?

Comment: It might be that the auto-focusing of the text area is not yet happened at the time you start typing the text. Try adding a time delay before sending the keys.

Comment: @MahsumAkbas , I am selecting it through Javascript function which is coded during development. Even though if I use the JS function for typing the text too, that will not come under proper testing. That is the reason.

Comment: @alecxe, It is pasting the text, But the actual scenario is I have to type and wait for auto suggestion popup.

Comment: @MahsumAkbas If any field is focussed we can send text inside it if it is editable. To focus for that area we can navigate through tap.

Comment: @alecxe I have given time for it, Even in debug mode auto suggestion is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent driver and selenium version's sendkeys are actually working like a typing case. Hence this problem is resolved by a selenium update.